# Не запускается IntelliJ IDEA что делать?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Пробую запустить IntelliJ IDEA сначала висит в диспетчере задач потом закрывается пробовал переустанавливать ничего не выходит

Comment: Вам с тем же вопросом сюда: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA , это будет гораздо продуктивнее. У вас запросят логи-конфиги, посоветуют что сделать и как запустить - и всё это сделают самые большие знатоки данной IDE - авторы.

Comment: Обычно, это происходит из-за версии JRE - возможно на компе стоит не православная версия. Рекомендуется таки использовать версию JRE которая поставляется вместе с IDEA

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте почистить кеш, почистить реестр, заново поставить IntelliJ IDEA.Возможно антивирус блокирует, протестировать отключить его.  Какие технические характеристики вашего пк ?